# how to create a table in sas to view the count of column variable with respect to another?

Tags: sas, dataset

I have data set as follows:

```
id a b
1  1 1
2  3 4
3  1 0
4  2 3
```

Where a and b have values (0-4).I want to create a view like this:

```
a/b 0 1 2 3 4
0   3 5 0 0 0
1   4 4 0 0 0
2   2 3 0 0 6
```

Basically i want to get count of a with respect to b. How can i create view in sas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present the counts using `Proc TABULATE` with `CLASSDATA` option for completeness.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(123);
  do id = 1 to 1000;
    a = rand('integer',0,4);
    do until (b ne 3);
      b = rand('integer',0,4);
    end;

    output;
  end;
run;

data allpairs;
  do a = 0 to 4;
  do b = 0 to 4;
    output;
  end;
  end;
run;

ods html file='output.html' style=plateau;

options missing = '0';

proc tabulate data=have classdata=allpairs;
  class a b;
  table a=' ', b*n=' '*[style=[textalign=center cellwidth=3em]] / box='a';
run;

ods html close;
```

Output:
[image]